# Set a JFrame to appear in center not working?

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a swing application and I created a log in form. I set it appear in center of the screen but not working :( I tried two ways **(1)** and **(2)** but both not working.
I cant understand why. Because both of the solutions were in this site.

My Code:

```
public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public LoginForm() {    

        /*Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-                         this.getSize().height/2);*/  // ----> (1)

        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // ----> (2)


        initComponents();
    }


    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private java.awt.Label label1;

    private void initComponents() {


        setUndecorated(true);

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField1 = new RoundJTextField(20);
        jPasswordField1 = new RoundJPasswordField(20);
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        label1 = new java.awt.Label();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(5, 0, 0, 0));
        setName("LogInFrame"); // NOI18N
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Username");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Password");


        label1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        label1.setText("UAC Login");

        jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/windows_close_program.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setActionCommand("loginExit");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/go.JPG"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setActionCommand("LoginButton");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/join.JPG"))); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("jButton3");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 198, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 262, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 55, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(22, 22, 22))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 207, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34))))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        



    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       this.setVisible(false);
       this.dispose();
       new RegistrationForm();
    }                                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Synth".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your order is off:

1. Add components first.
2. Then `pack()`
3. Then `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`  -- you're doing this too early
4. Then `setVisible(true)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer: jinks indeed! I think that we both were the first to up-vote the other as well!

Answer (score 4):

`setLocationRelativeTo` will use the frames current size to determine how best to achieve the desired results.  Seen as you've not actually added anything to the frame AND you've not set it's size, the only value it has to go on is `0x0` (size).

Try move `setLocationRelativeTo` after `initComponents`, but adding `pack` before you call it, for example...

```
public LoginForm() {    
    /*Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-                         this.getSize().height/2);*/  // ----> (1)
    initComponents();
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // ----> (2)
}
```

Comment: +1 Was going to write an answer, and instantly two thunder has appeared out of no where, stopping me in the middle.

Comment: @sage Gotta be quick in this game ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **netBeanIDE 7.**3. you may do this as.
->in design ,right click -> select properties and
[image]

and checked generate center.it will solve your problem without looking into code.
Hope it may help u.

Comment: lol. I will give you a  +1 too for understanding that he is actually working with NetBeans!